# hoc pacto a synonym for quo modo?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom

I am working through the notorious Rosetta Stone Latin and they have the phrase "hoc pacto" seemingly as a synonym for quo modo. So, for example, there are sentences like:

Solum hoc pacto purgandum est. (The floor must be cleaned like this.)

I could not really find this meaning in Lewis & Short. Pacto seems to mean an agreement or bargain, so I am trying to figure how they getting this "in this way" idiom. Is there some other noun pactus that I am unaware of or something?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it is under the word **pacisco** as follows at the end as the neuter participle:

(β) Transf., in gen., abl. pacto (like ratione and modo), manner, way, means (class.): percontat Aeneas, quo pacto Troiam urbem liquerit, Naev. Bell. Pun. 2, 1: si non fecero ei male aliquo pacto, Plaut. Bacch. 3, 6, 27; id. Am. prol. 137: nescio quo pacto semper hoc fit, how, Cic. Mur. 21, 43; id. Quint. 17: non tacebo umquam alio pacto, nisi, etc., Plaut. Rud. 5, 3, 46: aliquo pacto verba his dabo, Ter. Heaut. 4, 4, 13: quoquo pacto tacito est opus, id. Ad. 3, 2, 44: si nullo alio pacto, id. Phorm. 2, 1, 71: alio pacto docere, Cic. Inv. 1, 21, 30: fieri nullo pacto potest, ut, etc., id. Fin. 1, 8, 27; Ter. And. 1, 5, 12: servi mei si me isto pacto metuerent, Cic. Cat. 1, 7, 17; Hor. Ep. 1, 6, 10; 1, 8, 13: hoc pacto, Verg. G. 2, 248.